# Connecting to socket on Tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, tomcat

I'm trying to connect from a standalone applet to a servlet running on tomcat:

Servlet

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException { 
    super.init(config);
    // Start a daemon thread 
    try { 
        daemonThread = new Daemon(this);
        daemonThread.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { 
    }
}

protected int getSocketPort() { 
    return 8080;
}

public void handleClient(Socket client){ 
    new ScribbleThread(this, client).start();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("<html><body bgcolor=pink text=red>");
    sb.append("<h1 align=center>RUNNING</h1><hr>");
    sb.append("</body></html>");
    out.println(sb);
    out.close();
}
}
```

Servlet's `init()` creates this:

```
class Daemon extends Thread { 
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private SocketServlet servlet;

public Daemon(SocketServlet servlet) { 
this.servlet = servlet;
}

public void run() { 
    try { 
        // Create a server socket to accept connections 
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(servlet.getSocketPort());
    }
    catch (Exception e) { 
        return;
    }
    try { 
        while (true) { 
            try { 
                servlet.handleClient(serverSocket.accept());
            }
            catch (IOException ioe) { 
            }
        }
    }
```

I have this deployed by eclipse to TomCat. My question is what address does my applet need to make the socket to? When `i visit http://localhost:8080/scrabServ/connect` I see the 'RUNNING' message from the `doGet()` so is that where it needs to point?

Applet:

```
public static String testConnection(){
    InputStream in = null; 
    try { 
        // Make socket connection to servlet
        String servlet = new String("localhost/scrabServ/connect");
        Socket socket = new Socket(servlet, 8080);
```

this gives me:

```
Exception in testConnection()java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost/scrabServ/connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
at scribble.Scribble.testConnection(Scribble.java:41)
at scribble.Scribble.main(Scribble.java:28)
```

and points to the `new Socket(servlet, 8080)` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have only to open a socket to `"localhost", 8080` and then issue a `GET scrabServ/connect` command. You can't open a socket to a specific URL.

To communicate with a servlet you do it via request parameters, basically issuing a GET command such as: http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/http_footnotes.html#getsubmit

Maybe you should use [URLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) instead. If you detail what exactly you want to do, maybe I can have a better idea of how to help you, maybe a HTTP server is not even needed for what you want to do.

Comment: I read that URLConnection is a single request, single response scheme. I need a constant connection. Can you explain what you mean by GET? How would I transfer a string "Test" to the servlets inputStream using GET?

Comment: @Sbram I expanded my answer a little bit.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I need to have multiple clients connected to the servlet so that they can interact with each other and be notified of each others actions.

Comment: @Sbram Ok, got it. You don't really need Tomcat or using a Servlet. You are looking into developing a Socket Server and Socket clients. Oracle has a great tutorial to help you understand how that works. Look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've been using that link as a sort of reference but I'm not sure if my understanding is correct. Eventually i want this to run on a network so that any connected computer with the applet can use it. So I was thinking that i would need to run the socket server on a tomcat so that it is always running and always accepting connections? If i write a socket server as described in that tutorial and have it located in a shared folder on the network will that serve the same purpose? And how do i keep it running constantly?

Comment: @Sbram You can run the socket server on any pc or server in the network (just run it from the command line after compiling and assure that your socket port accepts connections through the PC firewall) and just use ip address or fully qualified dns name to connect to it from any other pc or server in the network.